# Change Text Box size in Powershell Windows Forms

Tags: powershell, winforms

I am creating a Windows Form using Powershell that accepts user input in text boxes and am having trouble making the textboxes 'deeper' or 'taller'
I am using `$tb.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600, 700)` where `$tb` is the text box variable, and in the parameters whenever I change the width (600 in this case) it works no issue, but if I try to change the second parameter the box stays the same height

[image: This is what the form looks like, as you can see text box is very thin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) for providing the crucial pointers:</sup>

When using [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms):

- For a ***single-line* text box** (a [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox) instance whose `.Multiline` property is set to `$false` (the default)), the **height is *automatically and invariably set***, namely to the height of *one line of text* (plus margins), based on the text box' font, which is by default inherited from their (immediate) parent control (the containing form or a container control they're nested inside of).

  - Any attempt to set a height manually - whether via `.Height` or via `.Size` - is *quietly ignored*.
- It follows from the above that **you can only control the height of a single-line text box *indirectly*, namely by changing its *font size***.

  - Given that controls inherit their font from their parent control, they are usually *proportional* by default, which makes increasing a single control's font size an unusual scenario.

---

Here's **self-contained sample code** that shows how to increase the height of a single-line text box by increasing its font size, and how to control a multiline text box' height as usual, via `.Size` (or `.Height`):

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create a sample form.
$form = [Windows.Forms.Form] @{ 
  Text = 'Form with Text Boxes'
  ClientSize = [Drawing.Point]::new(500, 110)
}

# Create the controls and add them to the form.
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(

    [Windows.Forms.Label] @{
        Text     = 'Foo:'
        Location = [Drawing.Point]::new(10, 10)
        AutoSize = $true
    }

    # Single-line text box.
    [Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{
      Text     = 'Single-line'
      Location = [Drawing.Point]::new(50, 10)
      # Set the width.
      Width = 200
      # Note: For *single-line* text boxes, the height is *automatically and invariably set*,
      #       namely to the height of *one line of text* based on the text box' font (plus margins).
      #       Any attempt to set a height manually - whether via .Height or via .Size - 
      #       is *quietly ignored*.
      # It follows from the above that you can control the height *indirectly*, by changing
      # the *font size*.
      Font     = [Drawing.Font]::new($form.Font.Name, 24)
    }

    # Multiline text box.
    [Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{
      Multiline = $true
      Text     = "Multi-`r`nline" # Note: use "`r`n" (CRLF), not just "`n"
      Location = [Drawing.Point]::new(280, 10)
      # Multiline text boxes DO allow setting a height too.
      Size = [Drawing.Size]::new(200, 90)
    }
))

$null = $form.ShowDialog()
```

Running this code shows the following form:

[image: screenshot of form]

If you comment out the `Font     = ...` line above, the single-line text box will use the same font as the other controls and will therefore render proportionally.